# Virtual Memory System

Tags: c, unix

I have a virtual memory system that consists of:-

```
• 32-bit virtual address
• 4-kbyte virtual page size
• 32-bit Page Table Entry (PTE)
• 2-Gbyte physical memory
```

I have been asked to find the number of physical frames available in the system and the size (in bytes) of the page table.

I have found the answer to the amount of physical frames, which i think is

```
physical memory/virtual page size

2^31/2^12 = 2^19 = 524,288
```

Firstly i want to know if that is correct.

Secondly, i would like to calculate the size of the page table in bytes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: addresses are unsigned, so the amount of physical frames is `2^32/2^12`. The PTE size will depend on how many hierarchies the page table has, they generally come in hierarchies. With just a single hierarchy you will have `#[of physical frames]*sizeof(void*)`.

Comment: woudnt 2^32 make the physical memory size 4gb? @SergeyL.

Comment: Yeah. But you should ideally clarify the question wether by physical frames is meant the amount of actually available random access memory or addressable memory. The addressable memory is independent from the amount of attached DIMMS and can map not just to the DIMMS, but also registers within PCI devices, etc...

Answer (score 0):

LA(logical address) = 32 bits 
=> LAS(Logical address space ) =2<sup>32</sup> bytes
PA(physical address) =30 bits
=> PAS(Physical address space ) =2<sup>30</sup> bytes

we know, `page size ==frame size`

No. of pages= (LAS/page size)= 2<sup>32-12</sup> =2<sup>20</sup>= 1 M pages

No. of frames =(PAS/frame size) = 2<sup>30-12</sup> = 2<sup>18</sup> frames

Since no. of entries in page table is equal to number of pages in LAS.
Hence `page table size = No. of entries * entry size`

=> page table size= 2<sup>20</sup>* 4 Bytes= 2<sup>22</sup> Bytes.